# Issue sending XML request as in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, xmlhttprequest, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

i tried to send xml request in jmeter as `**<Calc><Info>**`.. but  i recive request as &lt ; CalcReq > &lt ; Info > please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter should send the request "as it is", it might be the case your application does [escaping of the XML special characters](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/xml-escaped-chars.html)

Demo:

[image]

In general it's not possible to come up with the comprehensive answer without seeing your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration, and request body/headers from the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. It might be the case you didn't add the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header using the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) so your application doesn't know how to properly deal with the request.

More information: [Building a WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)